# Repeat failing promise for n times wrapper error in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a wrapper that calls an async function:

```
function fetchAPI(arg1: number, arg2: number, arg3: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      myFetchFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3).then((r: any) => {
        if (!r) {
          reject("Error 01")
        }
        resolve(r)
      })
    } catch {
      reject("Error 01")
    }
  })
}
```

Since the API I am querying is quite unstable, it occurs frequently that the `fetchAPI` function rejects.

Because of this, I make another function that calls `fetchAPI`, if it rejects it will repeat the call at most 3 times (waiting 1s) and if it fails all the times it will just resolve with `undefined`. While if it goes through any of the 3 times, it will simply resolve with the correct response.

```
function fetchAPIRepeat(arg1: number, arg2: number, arg3: string, n: number = 0) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fetchAPI(arg1, arg2, arg3).then((r) => {
      resolve(r)
    }).catch(() => {
      if(n < 3) {
        console.log("Partial error: " + n)
        sleep(1000).then(() => {
          resolve(fetchAPIRepeat(arg1, arg2, arg3, n + 1))
        })
      } else {
        resolve(undefined)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I would like to create a 'general wrapper' which would operate as the `fetchAPIRepeat` function, but for any promise function I pass it through.

This is what I have tried, however it doesn't work:

```
function promiseRepeatWrapper(fn: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>, n: number = 0, ...args: any[]) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    fn(args).then((r) => {
      resolve(r)
    }).catch(() => {
      if(n < 3) {
        console.log("Partial error: " + n)
        sleep(1000).then(() => {
          resolve(this.errorWrapper(fn, n + 1, args))
        })
      } else {
        resolve(undefined)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

By 'doesn't work' I mean that the console logs the 'Partial error' for three times, and then resolves with undefined, despite being sure that the promise goes through correctly all three of the times:

```
Partial error: 0
Partial error: 1
Partial error: 2
```

Other than helping me fix the function, I am also interested in error-handling design improvements for my promise-repeat pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: Could your error possibly have something to do with how you are passing your arguments through?  How exactly are you invoking the `promiseRepeatWrapper` method?  How is the function (`fn`) you pass in defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with async/await. You do not need to pass that args again. You can do it will a lot more generic approach. Where you can pass who many times to retry, and how much to wait after retry

Here is a [typescript playgorund](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gQwJZQGIgE4wLwwBRRIC2ApiAK5QBcMY5RARiRgJQ0AKGIRSEJAPADcQSACYA%20HJIDeAKBgKYGElHIYwtEnBiduvEnjzKIIADaCSLKTDmK7MPlAAqxMpUNXsk42Yt4WADQwhKQUUCwA3PKKAL6RsjGysggQAJ5gwDAAZuQZhOBKKhipujx8-E7ieFlgNP7WpfoV4kHKAA4kCLC4AMytRakAgllQzDgwAIwADDNsOlxlApU20QqmKjDAaspgUINQUG1E3ZNRdnAAFkjreFsYO3sHR7D8vVa29gpQxSufn8qqdQwBCIFDZMD%20M5-GKbLrAC74Sy-P52O4PfaHY4wADUuAmUJRChByFgoLQmCMA2Go1YBPsiTsiVWMAA9CywVlkOtRDAesFXBAYEgNAglCA4MyoBcuNowFoYABRe4UgBEAGEEGAwCBYKIQMErhAVfEmWyYE4SNAIEl1rAuqMiG0TvjZKBIHa0hkAPIdDBdJDgABKlpAFggXrAAGUSG6ebh6l5kQokFl8PaSI7uthcAAmGDvZl2dOZnF4ul2AFqDSNPgAOh85gMKoAmp0Lsa6TCSKY%20En7MWnaXToXFJWgTWSPWSAArGNQPAqgCS2S5JFEHeZiSZbugwNMiFSEFQXPGCZkzLH1YW%20ins%20A86X8Gupj3B8FnOuG6ZsgBxQnHmsFJ0mAH1mH9IMQzDCNo1jfwWFrKUSAhYxrB3MxJ1MEAAHNKQgFh4h-AZ-zPV8EEPY9rjghCLiQ3DUPAEx1lrTCcOMfDa2AOELjwEh6MgdDmOwnj8IiIA)

```js
const waitFor = (timeout: number): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), timeout);
    });
}

async function retryPromise<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>, repeat = 3, retryAfter = 1000): Promise<T> {
    let currentAttpmt = 1;
    while(currentAttpmt <= 3) {
        try {
            return await fn();
        } catch (e) {
            currentAttpmt += 1;
            await waitFor(retryAfter);
        }
    }

    //it failed 3 times in a row
    throw new Error("Cannot do this");
}
```